# How do I encode a Binary blob as Unicode blob?

Tags: c#, .net, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I'm trying to store a Gzip serialized object into Active Directory's "Extension Attribute", more info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms980479(EXCHG.65).aspx).  This field is a Unicode string according to it's [oM syntax](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961740.aspx) of 64.

What is the most efficient way to store a binary blob as Unicode? Once I get this down, the rest is a piece of cake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are, of course, many ways of reliably packing an arbitrary byte array into Unicode characters, but none of them are very efficient. It is *very unfortunate* that ActiveDirectory would choose to use Unicode for data that is not textual in nature. It’s like using a string to represent a 32-bit integer, or like using Nutella to write a love letter.

My recommendation would be to “play it safe” and use an ASCII-based encoding such as `base64`. The reason I recommend this is because there is already a built-in .NET implementation for this:

```
var base64Encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray);

var original = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Encoded);
```

In theory you could come up with an encoding that is more efficient than this by making use of more of the Unicode character set. However, in order to do so *reliably*, you would need to know quite a bit about Unicode.

Comment: Just to be fair to MSFT, there are other binary properties that I could use but the client wants me to use "extension attributes" which are Unicode. There are Byte[] in other spots too. I like Nutella love letters. +1

Answer (score 1):

Normally, this would be the way to convert between bytes and Unicode text:

```
// string from bytes
System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes);

// bytes from string
System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(bytes);
```

**EDIT**:
But since not every possible byte sequence is a valid Unicode string, you should use a method that can create a string from an arbitrary byte sequence:

```
// string from bytes
Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray);

// bytes from string
Convert.FromBase64String(base64Encoded);
```

(Thanks to **@Timwi** who pointed this out!)

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to keep my brain sharp while I'm on painkillers from my motorcycle injury.  I *think* I should have known this.  Just perfect

Comment: @MakerOfThings7 - Don't worry, it was unknown to me too until I actually needed it. :)

Comment: **This answer is completely wrong.** If you use this, you will lose data. `Encoding.Unicode` encapsulates UTF-16, and not all byte arrays are valid UTF-16. Consider arrays with odd numbers of bytes, or byte sequences with lone surrogates, for example. Neither are valid UTF-16 and would generate a string that doesn’t turn back into the original byte array.

Comment: @Timwi - Thanks, I did not think about it. If ASCII encoding would fix it, wouldn't it be also a solution to use `System.Text.Encoding.ASCII`? In theory, every byte has an ASCII counterpart, right?

Comment: @Venemo: No, of course not — half of all bytes are not valid ASCII characters! The encodings in `System.` **`Text`** `.Encoding` are meant to encode **text** as the name implies. You should use an encoding that is *designed for arbitrary byte data*. Base64 is an example of that.

Comment: @Timwi - When looking at an ASCII code table, there seem to be 256 possible values for an ASCII character, which correspond to the number of possible `byte` values. Anyways, I edited my answer and corrected it. I am ashamed of making such a mistake. :(

Comment: @Venemo: Then you are looking at a code table that **doesn’t represent ASCII**. Just run `Encoding.ASCII.GetString(new byte[] { 63 })` and then `Encoding.ASCII.GetString(new byte[] { 129 })` (hint: you get the same answer for both). You are looking at one that perhaps represents Latin-1 (ISO-8859-1) or Windows-1252. However, *even in those not all 256 possible values have a valid character*. The non-Unicode encodings turn several possible bytes values into question marks.

Comment: @Timwi - I was looking at http://www.ascii-code.com/ - According to this, both `?` and `á` are valid ASCII characters. Anyways, as I said, I'm glad you pointed out this mistake! :)

Comment: @Venemo: Well that website is wrong. It shows the [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) character set, not [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).